# Building a new strategy for Omniauth, but Omniauth can't find it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I'm new to Rails and to Omniauth, so sorry in advance for the dumb
question.

I'm trying to do an Omniauth strategy for the Deezer website.
http://www.deezer.com/en/developers/simpleapi/oauth

First, I set up a basic rails application to test the Facebook strategy.
Here is my code in Github :
https://github.com/geoffroymontel/omniauth-test

And it works fine. Good.

Then I added those files in my app lib directory

```
lib/omniauth-deezer.rb
lib/omniauth/deezer.rb
lib/omniauth/deezer/version.rb
lib/omniauth/deezer/strategies/deezer.rb
```

and added

```
provider :deezer, ENV['DEEZER_APP_ID'],
ENV['DEEZER_APP_SECRET'], :perms => 'basic_access,email'
```

in

```
config/initializers/omniauth.rb
```

But when I start the app with

```
rails s
```

I get the following error message

```
/home/geoffroy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/omniauth-1.0.2/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:33:in `rescue in provider': Could not find matching strategy for  :deezer. You may need to install an additional gem (such as omniauth-deezer). (LoadError) from /home/geoffroy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/omniauth-1.0.2/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:30:in `provider'
```

Thanks for your help

Best

Geoffroy

Comment: I added 

    require 'omniauth-deezer'

in initializers/omniauth.rb and it worked.

Now I don't understand why I need it and Facebook does not but...

Answer (score 4):

I added

```
require 'omniauth-deezer'
```

in initializers/omniauth.rb and it worked.

I don't really understand why I need it and Facebook doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Upgrading to 1.0](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Upgrading-to-1.0) doc it is mentioned that Omniauth needs a gem for every provider now, so you'll have to move your provider to a gem eventually.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to debug my strategy outside of a GEM, otherwise it's a bit painful to debug.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, if you want to add your own omniauth strategy, add this to your gemfile

```
gem 'omniauth-mystrategy', :path => '~/full-path-to-the-omniauth-folder/'
```

You´ll be using the local repository feauture of the gemfiles. 
In the official bundler page you´ll see how to use remote repos also.

http://gembundler.com/v1.3/gemfile.html